# Why does the Zodiacal light vary between dawn and dusk?

Tags: astronomy

According to several pages, in the Fall the Zodiacal light is better seen at dawn than at dusk:

> In the mid-latitudes, the zodiacal light is best observed in the western sky in the spring after the evening twilight has completely disappeared, or in the eastern sky in the autumn just before the morning twilight appears. -- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiacal_light)

Why is there a difference between dawn and dusk in its appearance? Is the Zodiacal light visible in the evening *at all* in the Fall?

Comment: My wild guess (and I may have gotten my directions all mixed up) is that this avoids looking toward the brightest part of the Milky Way. Hopefully someone more qualified can chime in.